# MongoDB 3.2 wiredTiger performing better than MongoDB 3.4 wiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

In my local I ran the [iibench-mongodb](https://github.com/mdcallag/iibench-mongodb) benchmark with mongo 3.2 & 3,4 with wiredTiger. In my tests mongo 3.2 wiredTiger seems to be performing better than mongo 3.4 wiredTiger for both insert & query.  Is this expected and why is the latest mongo performing worse than the previous release?

Environment -

- Mac OS X - 10.11.6
- Processor - 2 GHz Intel Core i7
- RAM - 8GB
- Mongo is started as `sudo ./mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger  --dbpath /tmp/data/mongodb/wired2/`
- The `/tmp/data/mongodb/wired2/` is deleted before each test run and mongo is started again with the empty `/tmp/data/mongodb/wired2/`
- The test parameters for iibench-mongodb can be found in [github](https://github.com/debraj-manna-jabong/iibench-mongodb/blob/master/run.simple.bash.Ln.Qn).
- Mongo Version Used in test 3.4.1 and 3.2.8
- Java 1.8.0_77

Below are the results of my test. It represents the average of 3 runs:-

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems that all the features included in the new versions are slowing the database

Benchmark between all versions: https://medium.com/@hartator/mongodb-4-2-vs-4-0-3-6-3-4-and-3-2-benchmarks-ee96a09ef231

[image]

But most of the benchmark are realized on standalone architecture, we can hope that performances are better on new version with a replicaset architecture, but i didn't found any benchmark so far..